# reading KMS SES encrypted emails with with boto3

Tags: python, encryption, boto3, amazon-ses, amazon-kms

I'm trying to replicate the code found in the below link to python/boto3:
https://github.com/gilt/node-s3-encryption-client/issues/3

however, Im stuck at getting the plain text from KMS with below code :

```
metadata = s3.head_object(Bucket='my bucket', Key='myencryptedemail00045')
kmsKeyBase64 = metadata['Metadata']['x-amz-key-v2']
iv = metadata['Metadata']['x-amz-iv']
taglen = (int(metadata['Metadata']['x-amz-tag-len']))/8
algo = metadata['Metadata']['x-amz-cek-alg']
encryptionContext = json.loads(metadata['Metadata']['x-amz-matdesc'])
kmsKeyBase = base64.b64decode(kmsKeyBase64)
response = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=kmsKeyBase, EncryptionContext=encryptionContext)
print (response)
```

The plain text output with boto3 shows something like this :

```
 {u'Plaintext': '\x13I&\x99\xfd\x07\x12\x13\x08M\xf4\x8f\xc4\xae\xc1\x9c\x16\xc2\x88\xaf\xda\xf7\xcf\xfe\x07\xa1\xb7S\x1d\n%\xd7'
```

If I use the same input with kms decrypt in AWS CLI, Im getting the right output, as below :

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo 'AQIDAHh/JCD4iDXb1vJh8MhaLBj6MyPnIB57hOtOlVzmpYZUereim0TFFcTueWN+w0Njd4IhPAAAAfjB8BgkqhkiereungbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMvYra4oU2QfFPI0tdAgEQgDuYGmtfQf/1reukNRiD6oGrv3BJuztdkeVrpPxkGzEY25otr143WKrA0YCEcmILYPfXOn3OJT2CShCH31w==' | base64 -d) --encryption-context '{"aws:ses:source-account": "XXXXXXXX", "aws:ses:message-id": "v235k9p8t2jf45u9dlnh6i45sc163di3a2m3u081", "kms_cmk_id": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXX:alias/rockondel-ses", "aws:ses:rule-name": "encrypt-test"}'
```

CLI Output :

```
{
"Plaintext": "E0kmokU0HEhIujfSPxKyUhjnBbCiK/a98/+B6G3Ux0KJdc=", 
"KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXX:key/XXxxxXX-06ce-49f1-3452-XXxxxXXXXxx"
```

}

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you that the output of the AWS CLI is just base64 encoding the Plaintext.

```
from base64 import b64encode
b64encode(b'\x13I&\x99\xfd\x07\x12\x13\x08M\xf4\x8f\xc4\xae\xc1\x9c\x16\xc2\x88\xaf\xda\xf7\xcf\xfe\x07\xa1\xb7S\x1d\n%\xd7')
b'E0kmmf0HEhMITfSPxK7BnBbCiK/a98/+B6G3Ux0KJdc='
```